# How to Reset form on successful registration only, yet keep content when when submission fails

Tags: php, html, css, forms, codeigniter

```
<h3 class="text-upper background-blue1 top-margin-reg"> Register now</h3>
<h5 class="text-grey padding-bottom-20 padding-top-10">Don't have an Account?</h5>
<form action="<?=site_url('home/register')?>" method="post" class="border-left ">
    <?php if(isset($message)) '<span class="text-success txt-upper">'. $message . '</span>';?>
    <table class="table " style="margin-left: 11%;">
        <tr class="col-md-5">
            <td class="login-textfield">
                <input type="text" id="firstname" class="background-grey" placeholder="First name" name="firstname" value="<?php echo set_value('firstname')?>" required id="firstname" />
                <?php echo form_error( 'firstname'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="col-md-5">
            <td class="login-textfield">
                <?php echo form_input( 'lastname',set_value( 'lastname'), 'placeholder="Last name", class="background-grey" id="lastname" required id="lastname"')?>
                <?php echo form_error( 'lastname'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="col-md-5">
            <td class="login-textfield">
                <?php echo form_input( 'phone',set_value( 'phone'), ' placeholder="Phone Number", class="background-grey" id="phone" required id="phone"')?>
                <?php echo form_error( 'phone'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="login-textfield">
                <?php echo form_input( 'username',set_value( 'username'), ' placeholder="Username", id="user_name" class="background-grey" required id="user_name"')?>
                <?php echo form_error( 'username'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="login-textfield">
                <?php echo form_input( 'email',set_value( 'email'), ' placeholder="Email", class="background-grey" id="email" required id="email"')?>
                <?php echo form_error( 'email'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="login-textfield">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="background-grey" id="password" required id="password" |matches[password_confirm]/>
                <?php echo form_error( 'password'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="login-textfield">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="background-grey" id="password_confirm" required id="password_confirm" />
                <?php echo form_error( 'password_confirm'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="login-textfield text-grey radio-pad">Gender
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked/>male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />female</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="login-textfield text-center padding-top-10">
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-width-120 button-pos" type="submit" value="Register" name="register" id="form" style="width: 121%;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I am sorry but the code elements were not working for this. The above text is my code, I want to reset the form when submission is successful but keep the content in it when there are validation errors.

Controller Code:-

```
public function register(){
    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
    $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'This field is required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<small class="text-danger txt-upper">', '</small>');

    // Process the form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
    {
        if($this->user_m->add_user())
        {
            $this->data['message']= "You are registered successfully. Please login" ;


        }

        else
        {
            $this->data['message']= "Failed to register";
        }

    }
                $this->data['subview'] = 'home/login';
                $this->load->view('_layout_main_1', $this->data);
            //  $this->load->view('home/login', $this->data);
        }
```

Comment: Please post your controller code too !!

Comment: Are you using form_validation helper in the controller?

Comment: use session and save posted values in there and display it back at the form. Destroy sessions if submission success.

Comment: hey ryan, I'm sorry but could you be more brief

Answer (score 0):

Its best for you to use session array when you have an error and show values in form . but when you have an error simply redirect it and your form will be reset after submission.

Comment: Can you please explain how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller code needs to change as below (and I am guessing, you know this already) :

```
   // Process the form
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
{
    if($this->user_m->add_user())
    {
        $this->data['message']= "You are registered successfully. Please login" ;
     // Call login screen here, for example :
     redirect('login', 'location');

    }

    else
    {
        $this->data['message']= "Failed to register";
    }

}
```

Change the form code as below : (remove the call to set_value)

```
            <td class="login-textfield">
            <?php echo form_input( 'phone','', ' placeholder="Phone Number", class="background-grey" id="phone" required id="phone"')?>
            <?php echo form_error( 'phone'); ?>
```

Explanation :
On form_validation failure - code_igniter has not yet exited the form, and so the values entered in the fields will still be available without the use of set_value.

On successful registration you don't care as you are moving to a new form - login form.

Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: It did not work, Resetting the Form for Failed Validation and on Success the message is not being displayed